# Hover title over an SVG circle

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Using snapsvg.io, I would like to know if it's possible to add a title to an SVG circle like you can with the `<img>` tag when hovering over the image but on a SVG circle?

Using some example code from snapsvg.io website:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);
bigCircle.attr({
    fill: "#bada55",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 5
});
```

How can I achieve a hover title over this bigCircle to display some title text? I'd like to do this in plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a title child of the circle. There's no snap title creator but you can use Snap.parse to create one natively.

```js
var s = Snap("#svg");
var bigCircle = s.circle(150, 150, 100);
bigCircle.attr({
    fill: "#bada55",
    stroke: "#000",
    strokeWidth: 5
});

var title = Snap.parse('<title>This is a title</title>');
bigCircle.append(title);
```

```css
html, body, svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://svg.dabbles.info/snap.svg.js"></script>
<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Excellent - just want I needed. Assuming I can apply this to text as well?

Comment: try it and see :-)

Comment: All good Robert - assumed it would work. You seem to know your SVG elements very well. Would it be possible to ask you onespecific question regarding an SVG image and how to add multiple circles evenly (layered) so that they do not overlap and stay within a certain region. Unsure how to determine this/develop?

Comment: Feel free to ask another question on that subject.

Comment: Will do, but will get back onto it later on tonight. Thanks Robert.

Comment: Have just posted my new question - pls see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542867/how-to-calculate-a-region-of-an-svg-image-to-be-used-for-circles