# Clickable link on a SVG circle, text or line

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Using snapsvg.io, I would like to know if it's possible to add a clickable link such as a `<a href="somelink.com"/>My Link</a>` tag to an SVG text, circle or line.

An example here I have is text:

```
var s = Snap("#svg");
var text = s.text(x + 10, y - 5, 'My Text');
text.attr({
        fill: doesExist ? alert : textColorOK,
        fontSize: '10px',
        'font-weight': '600',
        'font-family': 'Arial Narrow, sans-serif',
        'text-anchor': 'start',
        cursor: doesExist ? 'pointer' : 'default'
      });
```

I'd like to do this with snapsvg.io. Furthermore, I want to do this in plain JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: Give it an `id` and use `$(id).click(function(){ window.location = "yourURL"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate the responses but ended up using a click event, say to a text element i.e.

```
text.click(function () {
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
});
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an [SVG `<a>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a).

I don't know Snap, and from my fast testings, I wasn't able to set the `xlink:href` directly from the library, but here is a workaround :

```js
var s = Snap("#mySVG1");

var a = s.el('a');

a.node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http://stackoverflow.com');

a.add(s.text(0, 100, "I'm a link"))
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/snap.svg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySVG1" height="200" width="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kaiido's answer is correct (so I am using that, so don't accept this as the answer), but just to extend that answer if it helps, you can add a plugin to do it, in case you need to do this a lot, so it could look like this...

```
Snap.plugin( function( Snap, Element, Paper, global ) {
    Element.prototype.a = function( link, element ) {
        var a = this.el('a');
        // prev was var a = s.el('a'); // but thats limited to just one paper.
        a.node.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', link);
        return a.add( element )
    };
});

var c = s.circle(20,20,20);
var t = s.text(0,100,'Hi there, click me')
s.a( 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', c).attr({ stroke: 'red', fill: 'red'})
s.a( 'http://www.stackoverflow.com', t).attr({ stroke: 'red', fill: 'red'})
```

Comment: this is good to add text links, but svg anchor has a lot of [permitted content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a#Usage_context), wouldn't it be better to replace `text`parameter with `element` instead, so you can make shapes anchored too ?

Comment: var a = s.el('a'); is supposed to be "var a = Snap.el('a');" ?

Comment: No, this wouldn't work, as Snap (as well as Paper) is essentially a function. So you need to use .el() on an instantiated object. However, it was an oversight (that happened to work as we typically just use one paper). To make it a bit better, we can swap s.el() to this.el() though. I'll update the answer, so you can see..."this" should be the s/Snap paper you use it on like in the example.