# A tag for plotly dash-svg?

Tags: html, svg, plotly-dash

I am developing a plotly dash app using dash-svg (below),
https://github.com/stevej2608/dash-svg

I have a problem to make an htmltag for svg graph using dash-svg.
I cannot find to make an link inside the svg graph, like "https://www.google.com".

If anyone knows the answer for "Clickable svg circle", please help me...

```
import dash
from dash import html
from dash_svg import Svg, G, Path, Circle


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Header([
        Svg([
            G([
                Path(d='...'),
                Circle(cx="420.9", cy="296.5", r='45.7'),
                Path(d='M520.5 78.1z')
            ], fill='#61DAFB')
        ], viewBox='0 0 841.9 595.3', className="App-logo", alt="logo"),
        html.P(["Edit ", html.Code("usage.py"), " and save to reload."]),
        html.A("Learn Dash", className="App-link", href="https://dash.plotly.com/",  target="_blank", rel="noopener noreferrer")
    ], className="App-header")
], className="App")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/37592540/16733101?

Comment: Yes bro, but I am looking find a way to make a HTML A funtionality using plotly dash-svg. I can't find it ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the Svg component as the children of html.A component, like this:

```
html.A(
            [
                Svg([
                    G([
                        Path(d='...'),
                        Circle(cx="420.9", cy="296.5", r='45.7'),
                        Path(d='M520.5 78.1z')
                    ], fill='#61DAFB')
                ], viewBox='0 0 841.9 595.3', className="App-logo", alt="logo"),

            ],
            target="_blank",href="https://google.com"
),
```

Comment: Wow you save me!